# how to send a request to google direction api to get a path in swift

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I'm new to swift and 
I'm creating an App that will show the location of the user and put a marker to that position. After the user moves. The marker would be removed and a new marker would be created. Now. I want to make markers on Point A and Point B into the app and show the route on the map. It shall use the nearest road on the map.
i already study the google map document but i need help i can't understand how to make a route between 2 points?

I would be happy if you help me, thank-you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Based from this [blog](https://www.raywenderlich.com/109888/google-maps-ios-sdk-tutorial), you need first to add the property `let locationManager = CLLocationManager()` that  will add and instantiate a `CLLocationManager` property named `locationManager`.

Next, find `viewDidLoad()` and add these two lines to the bottom that will make `MapViewController` the delegate of `locationManager` and request access to the user’s location.

```
locationManager.delegate = self
locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

From this related [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25296691/swift-get-users-current-location-coordinates), you have to instantiate the `CLLocationManager` class in `viewDidLoad()` like this:

```
// Ask for Authorisation from the User.
self.locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization() 

// For use in foreground
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}
```

Then in `CLLocationManagerDelegate` method you can get user's current location coordinates:

```
func locationManager(manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
    var locValue:CLLocationCoordinate2D = manager.location.coordinate
    print("locations = \(locValue.latitude) \(locValue.longitude)")
}
```

Then to [add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker), create a `GMSMarker` object that includes a `position` and `title`, and set its `map`. The following example demonstrates how to add a marker to an existing `GMSMapView` object. The marker is created at coordinates `10,10`, and displays the string "Hello world" in an info window when clicked.

```
let  position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Lastly, make a route between 2 points, you can check these links:

- [How to get route between two locations in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32493845/how-to-get-route-between-two-locations-in-ios)

> Now in `createRoute` method give that city name or what ever you want
>   as origin like this:
>
> ```
> @IBAction func createRoute(sender: AnyObject) {
>
>     let addressAlert = UIAlertController(title: "Create Route", message: "Connect locations with a route:", preferredStyle:
> ```
>
> UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
>
> ```
>     addressAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
>         //give a origin for route
>         textField.text = self.currentLocationName
>         textField.userInteractionEnabled = false
>     }
>
>     addressAlert.addTextFieldWithConfigurationHandler { (textField) -> Void in
>         textField.placeholder = "Destination?"
>     }
>
>
>     let createRouteAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Create Route", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default) { (alertAction) -> Void in
>         let origin = (addressAlert.textFields![0] as! UITextField).text as String
>         let destination = (addressAlert.textFields![1] as! UITextField).text as String
>
>         self.mapTasks.getDirections(origin, destination: destination, waypoints: nil, travelMode: nil, completionHandler: {
> ```
>
> (status, success) -> Void in
>                   if success {
>                       self.configureMapAndMarkersForRoute()
>                       self.drawRoute()
>                       self.displayRouteInfo()
>                   }
>                   else {
>                       println(status)
>                   }
>               })
>           }
>
> ```
>     let closeAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Close", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Cancel) { (alertAction) -> Void in
>
>     }
>
>     addressAlert.addAction(createRouteAction)
>     addressAlert.addAction(closeAction)
>
>     presentViewController(addressAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
> }
> ```

- [Drawing Route Between Two Places on GMSMapView in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22550849/drawing-route-between-two-places-on-gmsmapview-in-ios/22551085)

> First, get all points coordinates which are coming in route then add
>   these points latitude and longitude in path in will draw path
>   according to that
>
> ```
>      GMSCameraPosition *cameraPosition=[GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:18.5203 longitude:73.8567 zoom:12];
>         _mapView =[GMSMapView mapWithFrame:CGRectZero camera:cameraPosition];
>         _mapView.myLocationEnabled=YES;
>         GMSMarker *marker=[[GMSMarker alloc]init];
>         marker.position=CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(18.5203, 73.8567);
>         marker.icon=[UIImage imageNamed:@"aaa.png"] ;
>         marker.groundAnchor=CGPointMake(0.5,0.5);
>         marker.map=_mapView;
>         GMSMutablePath *path = [GMSMutablePath path];   
>         [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(18.520).doubleValue,@(73.856).doubleValue)];
>         [path addCoordinate:CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(@(16.7).doubleValue,@(73.8567).doubleValue)];
>
>         GMSPolyline *rectangle = [GMSPolyline polylineWithPath:path];
>         rectangle.strokeWidth = 2.f;
>         rectangle.map = _mapView;
>         self.view=_mapView;
> ```

Hope this helps!